# Calling ajax request from html page inside asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

I cannot get a simple ajax example to work from an html page inside my visual studio project.  It works fine from a webform (aspx):

...
webform1.aspx and form1.html
...

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
            alert("before json");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                data: "{name: bob }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }

            });
            alert("after json");
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
```

...
webform1.aspx and form1.html
...

```
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
                   onclick="ShowCurrentTime()" />
```

...
json.aspx
...

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
                + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

If I put the code in webform1.aspx, it works fine.  If I put it on form1.html, nothing comes back from json.aspx.  I am running the project in debug mode from my machine using vs2013.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update #1**

I checked fiddler and the server is returning the following result (500):

{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: bob.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at ...

Comment: Is form1.html in the same directory as webform1.aspx?

Comment: open the developer tools in your browser and look for any error in the Javascript console

Comment: Is form1.html loading jquery.js?

Comment: Yes, form1.html is in the same directory and webform1.aspx.  Yes, jquery is loaded, confirmed by calling if (window.jQuery)
        {
            // jQuery is loaded
            alert('jquery is loaded');
        }

Comment: Checked firefox browser console, no errors at all in console when button is pressed.  I just get the before/after alert.  Also tried in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is malformed. Strings need to be in quotes. Put `bob` in quotes and you should be good. I'm unsure why it's working on the ASP.NET page though, unless it has the quotes there.

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
        alert("before json");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "json.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: "{name: \"bob\" }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        });
        alert("after json");
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

Comment: Man do I feel dumb. Thanks buddy.

Comment: It's better when it's a dumb mistake instead of something that takes weeks to recode :)